# MQ objects creation using crtmqm command

Tags: ibm-mq

I have installed WebSphere MQ in my laptop and able to create MQ objects through MQ explorer.
When go to command prompt and run the crtmqm from MQ home/bin . I encountered " you are not authorised to perform this operation "
- I did installed MQ with my login and same login used to create MQ also.
- tried changing run--> services.msc and modify MQ installation permissions but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

MQ CLI commands can be run by the members of the mqm group, and by the members of Administrators.
If your user account isn't a member of mqm, then you will need to start cmd with the option Run as Administrator.